# Angular 2 Two Way Binding with ngClass

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, does ngClass have two-way binding?

currently i have something like following for a modal

```
<div class="modal autonomous" [(ngClass)]="{'modal-open' : modalState}">
...
</div>
```

everything works except there is javascript that manages this modal *outside* of this angular app. for example, the javascript (using jQuery) will remove the `modal-open` class when user clicks on certain area of the modal, but the `modalState` variable stays `true`. So next time when i try to open the modal in Angular by setting `modalState=true`, the modal stays closed presumbly because the variable hasn't changed (was already true).

so if possible, how to achieve ngClass two way binding in Angular 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not supported. `class` can only be set using bindings (like [ngClass]) but doesn't produce events when modified. The only way I see is polling if it is not possible to make the code that changes the classes fire an event after each change.

Comment: thanks! you mean fire event after updating `modalState` variable? how can i do that?

Comment: I meant jQuery to fire an event after it changed `class` for your component to listen and update `modalState` accordingly. Might be I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: can you give a quick example of how to listen to change event fired by jQuery in Angular 2? thanks!

Comment: `(event-name)="soSomething($event)` if the event is fired on the element where this is added or `(window:event-name)="soSomething($event)` to listen globally.